# Ubuntu doesn't boot

Tags: boot, 22.04

Booting my PC has an almost constant issue where it will not boot into Ubuntu 22.04. After several attempts it will boot without me seeming to change anything and then will reoccur after shutdown.

PC Specs:

```
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Kernel: 5.15.0-56-generic
MB: B550-I AORUS PRO AX
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 5600
RAM: 32GB
GPU: ADM Radeon RX 5500XT
```

I found the below errors in journalctl:

```
Dec 17 09:39:26 robinsia-B550I kernel: amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: Failed to enable requested dpm features!
Dec 17 09:39:26 robinsia-B550I kernel: amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: Failed to setup smc hw!
Dec 17 09:39:26 robinsia-B550I kernel: [drm:amdgpu_device_ip_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* hw_init of IP block <smu> failed -62
Dec 17 09:39:26 robinsia-B550I kernel: amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: amdgpu_device_ip_init failed
Dec 17 09:39:26 robinsia-B550I kernel: amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: Fatal error during GPU init
```

Comment: I have exactly the same issue with the RX 6600XT

Comment: I have found a method that prevents the issue so far. After I turn the PC on I enter the BIOS and just leave it there for about 5 minutes and go take care of something else. I haven't determined the minimum amount of time required yet. Then I close the BIOS and let it finish booting. So far this has consistently booted into ubuntu without the issue.

Comment: I found a different workaround: Turn the PC on, immediately turn it off again, wait 1 second, turn on again.

Comment: I will give that a try. Could it be a power/viloltage issue to the GPU?

Comment: I don't know. However, a Windows installation on the same machine does not exhibit this issue.